# Compute the Edge Automorphism Group of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How do you compute the [edge automorphism group](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EdgeAutomorphismGroup.html) of a graph? Using the command `GraphAutomorphismGroup`, you can compute the [automorphism group of the graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphAutomorphism.html), which consists of permutations  V-> V of the vertices of your graph such that the resulting graph is isomorphic to G. Each such permutation induces a permutation on the edges E->E of your graph. How do you compute this group of permutations of the edges?

Comment: `GraphAutomorphismGroup[LineGraph[g]]` as $\mathrm{Aut}^*[G]\cong\mathrm{Aut}[L(G)]$

Comment: You have the answer in the comment above. There is also `IGBlissAutomorphismCount` in IGraph/M which is going to be much faster than `GraphAutomorphismGroup` for large enough graphs, but slower for tiny graphs (due to overhead).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response all! @Szabolcs, I will need to use IGBliss anyhow since my graphs have some "colored" vertices, as per my question from a few weeks ago :)